# znapzend throwing up errors attempting to delete old snapshots

Tags: znapzend

I am moving backup to znapzend. I see the following error on the backup server. However the backups are working fine and I can see the latest snapshots the backup server. The errors below pertain to old snapshots and I am not sure (a) if they matter or can be ignored (b) how to stop them:

> [ID 702911 daemon.warning] ERROR: cannot destroy snapshot(s)

.... followed by an old snapshot.

The snapshot referred to does not exist on the backup.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

znapzend complains if `zfs destroy fs@snapshot` fails ... but it will retry on the next round ... my guess is that there was a problem but it resolved itself and on the next round, the snapshot got destroyed without complaint.